# What are simple ways to ensure JavaScript file is never imported as module and is used as CLI?

Tags: javascript

I have a file that does dangerous jobs and must be used as CLI with `node` command directly. How can I be sure no developer ever imports it as module with `import 'file.js'` syntax in current project?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your functionality in this check which would allow you to handle it differently based on the usage.

```
if (require.main === module) {
    console.log('called directly');
} else {
    console.log('required as a module');
}
```

Comment: Is `require` available in module syntax?